# How to fill data in some of GridViewRow and leave some blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

ASP.net C#

I am creating a gridview having 5 rows containing detail of operations users have to perform. Detail of operations should be filled when it is completed. At a time any number of operation details can be filled.
In gridview, first Item-template contains Label (for operation name) and others are textbox (for other details).

If any user has filled 3 rows then rest of two rows should be blank.

My problem is how to bind those 3 rows filled previously leaving two bottom rows available for entry.

My Gridview design is :

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table-bordered gridStyle" runat="server" ShowFooter="True"
    ID="grdOperationEntry" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operation">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("operation_title") %>' ID="lblOperationName" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Completion">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date_completed") %>' CssClass="form-control"
                    ID="txtDateCompletion" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Taken">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("time_taken") %>' ID="txtTimeTaken" CssClass="form-control" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Score">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("score_gain") %>' ID="txtScore" CssClass="form-control" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reported To">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reported_to") %>' ID="txtReportedTo"
                    CssClass="form-control" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Label with all TextBoxes in GridView and set them visible false and bind also Label from database. I have added an example `TemplateField` to below, you can do it for all other:

```
.....
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Completion">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="False" Text='<%# Eval("date_completed") 
                   ID="lblDateCompletion" %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Visible="False" Text='<%# Eval("date_completed") %>' 
                   ID="txtDateCompletion" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
.....
```

In `RowDataBound` event set them visible true:

```
protected void grdOperationEntry_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if gridview row not a header or footer
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // get controls by id from gridview and cast them
        Label lblDateCompletion = e.Row.FindControl("lblDateCompletion") as Label;
        TextBox txtDateCompletion = e.Row.FindControl("txtDateCompletion") as TextBox;

        if (lblDateCompletion.Text == null)
            txtDateCompletion.Visible = true;
        else
            lblDateCompletion.Visible = true;

        // perform same for other controls
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add `OnRowDataBound` property to your GridView `<asp:GridView ID="grdOperationEntry" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grdOperationEntry_RowDataBound" >`